# Give focus to file when clicking on it in the Explorer View

Tags: visual-studio-code, focus

When clicking on a file from the Explorer View, VSCode doesn't give focus to the file, so you then need to click inside that file to start typing. I'm pretty sure it was different before, and it would automatically give focus to the text editor.

Any idea if some option can be set to restore the old behaviour?

Comment: You could try to : (1) Disable all extensions to eliminate them as the cause, (2) Revert to an older VSCode version where it works and file a bug report.

Comment: Ok found the GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166118

Comment: I saw this too, where it said the fix is for Jan 2, 2023. It's long past now, but you can still vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was requested in several posts and was accepted by the
developers.

The latest request dates from Nov 11, 2022 :
[Setting to focus editor on mouse click #166118](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166118).
It was accepted on Jan 2, 2023, and will be implemented sometimes in the future.

You will need to keep on installing the latest versions of VSCode
as they come out, in the hope that the fix will arrive soon enough.